# Order of equivalence classes in finite fields

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

How can i easily determine the order of 
$$
[3] \in \mathbb{F}_{11}^\times
$$

By the way: $\mathbb{F}_{11}^\times =\mathbb{F}_{11}\setminus \{[0]\}$.

Fermat's little theorem states that the order of a group element
has to be a divisor of $p-1$ if $p$ is prime. Thus it should be $1, 2, 5$ or 10.

From 
$$
3² = 9 \equiv 9  \mod 11 \\
3^3 = 27 \equiv 5  \mod 11 \\
3^4 = 81 \equiv 4  \mod 11 \\
3^5 = 243 \equiv 1  \mod 11
$$
we see that $ord([3])=5$.
Is this correct?
and is there any faster way to "see" that without calculating it?

Comment: Did you realize you don’t have to calculate $3^5=243$ just $3^5=3^43\equiv4\times3=12\equiv1\mod11$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

**Hint for a faster way:** $5^2\equiv3\mod11$, and by Fermat's little theorem $5^{10}\equiv1\mod11.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a faster way. Since $3^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$, the order of $3$ must divide $10$. Therefore, there is no way that, for instance the order is $3$ or $4$.

Comment: OP indicated recognition that the order should be $1, 2, 5$, or $10$